# Dynkin-diagrams package arrow size modificaiton

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm currently trying to draw something with the `dynkin-diagrams` package and I don't really know how to modify the arrows that are produced. The documentation explains how one can reverse the arrow, but not how to enlarge it... Consider as example the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[indefinite edge/.style={ultra thick,densely dashed},
                      o/.style={ultra thick,fill=black!30!white,draw=black},
                      edge length=2cm, 
                      edge/.style={ultra thick}, 
                      root radius=.2cm]{F}{oooo}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

I tried to modify `arrow/.style`, but I'm doing something wrong since no changes happen. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: I will put a new version up on CTAN soon to deal with this, but I need to test it a little more first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could exploit the fact that the `dynkin-diagrams` package feeds the color to the arrow head using

```
\path[-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[\dynkin@arrow@color]},
```

This means you can pass *any* arrows parameters to the color key, i.e. not just the color but also the `length`, `width` and `line width` (and any other viable arrows parameter of section **16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips** of the pgf manual v3.1.5).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[indefinite edge/.style={ultra thick,densely dashed},
                      o/.style={ultra thick,fill=black!30!white,draw=black},
                      edge length=2cm, 
                      edge/.style={ultra thick}, 
                      root radius=.2cm,
                      arrow color={black,length=3mm,width=5mm,line width=2pt}]{F}{oooo}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Today's new version of `dynkin-diagrams` on CTAN allows using the expression `arrow style` as a synonym for `arrow color`, so that you can use the same solution as Schrödinger's cat, but it looks a little more natural. I suggest using `tikzset` to make global settings for your document, so that all Dynkin diagrams have the same style.

[image: An image of the F4 root system]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\tikzset{
    /Dynkin diagram,
        indefinite edge/.style={
            ultra thick,
            densely dashed
        },
        o/.style={
            ultra thick,
            fill=black!30!white,
            draw=black
        },
        edge length=2cm, 
        edge/.style={ultra thick}, 
        arrow style={black,
                length=3mm,
                width=5mm,
                line width=2pt
                },
        root radius=.2cm,
        mark=o}
\begin{document}
\dynkin F4
\end{document}
```